# Forcing headings to wrap in html

Tags: html, css, html-heading

I have a web page that displays a pdf document. In the header there is an image and an h1 tag that contains a name. When the name is too long, it gets cut off. How can I force it to wrap to the next line instead so that the entire name is displayed? I tried inserting a `style="white-space:normal"` but it doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post some example code that we look at to get a better idea of the problem?

Answer (score 26):

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Comment: make sure it is also white-space:normal

Answer (score 17):

It should have the combination of two:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
white-space: normal;
```

thanks to Tor and Alex :)

Answer (score 8):

`h1` tags wrap by default. If they're not, something in your CSS is overriding that default behaviour. If you can post a link to the site, we can quickly help you out. You might want to consider installing Firebug for Firefox - it'll let you right-click on the `h1` and view what styles are being applied to it, and from where they come.

Answer (score 1):

Is the header contained wihtin another element such as a div?  If so, check the overflow for that element and/or try setting it to visible like this:

```
style="overflow:visible;"
```

Comment: No, it's not within another element

Answer (score 1):

the `h1` tag has a zero line height

```
style="line-height:100%;"
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. It is not even related to the question.